# Why am I getting this "No known class" warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple test app to help me learn how to persist data from a NSMutableArray to a plist. Everything seems to be working well, until I try to save the data by calling a ViewController method called "saveData" in my AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [ViewController saveData];
}
```

I get a "No known class method for selector 'saveData', although the method is clearly declared in ViewController.h, like so:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  PlistTest
//
//  Created by Tim Jones on 10/30/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 TDJ. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;

@property NSMutableArray *mainActivityArray;



- (IBAction)buttonHit:(id)sender;

-(NSString *) getFilePath;
-(void) saveData;
-(void) loadData;


@end
```

and implemented in ViewController.m, thusly:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  PlistTest
//
//  Created by Tim Jones on 10/30/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 TDJ. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DataClass.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(NSString *) getFilePath
{
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PlistTestData"];
}

-(void) saveData
{
    [self.mainActivityArray writeToFile: self.getFilePath atomically:YES];
}
```

I imported the ViewController.h into AppDelegate.h.

I'm pretty green, so I expect the problem may be obvious to many here. Would sure appreciate some help.

Comment: What sort of tutorial are you following?

Comment: As a side-node: "I imported the ViewController.h into AppDelegate.h", you should only import a .h file into another .h file if you're extending a class or implementing a protocol. Otherwise you should use a 'foward declaration', which means putting @class MyClass instead of #import "MyClass.h". . . the reason for this is to avoid an import loop.

Comment: @Hot--In the "saveData" case I was loosely following a tutorial by Simon Allardice, but we diverged because of the way his template had instantiated the view controller. Sorry for not responding sooner--I'm having trouble understanding the way StackOverflow structures questions, answers and comments. They seem to shift around.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**

```
[ViewController saveData];
```

You are calling `saveData` method using class name `ViewController`.

But `saveData` is an instance method, not class method.

```
-(void) saveData;
```

**Fixes:**

1) Declare `saveData` as class method

```
+(void) saveData;
```

2) Call `saveData` using the object of `ViewController`.

```
ViewController *vControl = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[vControl saveData];
```

Comment: Most likely option 2 is the right one except it should be called on the existing instance, not a new one.

Comment: @rmaddy--I'm using a template (Xcode 5), and I don't see any place where ViewController is instantiated.

Comment: Yes, it's *very important* to *not* fall into the trap of coding #2 literally.  That creates an instance of ViewController, executes `saveData` on it, and then (apparently) discards the instance.  In such a case it's almost certain that `saveData` does nothing.

Comment: @TimJones - You need to figure out when/where to instantiate ViewController.  This is fundamental.

Comment: @Tim Jones: Since you're calling the method inside the view controller itself, you would use `self` to refer to the appropriate instance.

Comment: @Hot -- The song remains the same. I've tried instantiating the VC every way and in every place I can imagine. I've also located saveData in a similar number of locations. Nothing changes the contents of the plist. Sure could use more help!

Comment: You generally instantiate the view when you're ready to present it for the first time.

Comment: Among other obvious issues, my primary problem remains where and how to instantiate my various objects. I'm not lazy, but I'm getting depressed. I live in Mexico, and there's not another programmer within 100 miles. Hope I'm not violating protocol, but is there any chance you (or another volunteer) would take a look at this project? It's really small, and I expect someone with your ability could diagnose the problem within minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer (Midhun #2) can work, but I think you would be better off using the Application Did Enter Background Notification and skip the delegate.

Just add this to "view did load": it will call saveData whenever the app goes to background.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveData) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course, none of that will occur until he creates an instance.

Comment: @Hot Licks-- ok, I'm just thrashing now. I'm happy to do my own research, but I have no idea when or where to instantiate ViewController. I tried viewDidLoad, but nothing changed. The warnings are gone, the app builds and runs, but nothing ever gets saved to the plist.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, your issue is that your `[ViewController saveData]` method invocation clearly suggests that you're trying to call a "[class method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ClassMethod.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH8-SW1)", and you undoubtedly want to call your "instance method" (because it's your instance of your view controller that has the data you want to save). To achieve that, you have two basic choices:

1. You can have your app delegate call the `saveData` method in your view controller.

   In various comments, you mention that you've "tried instantiating the VC every way and in every place I can imagine." Don't. Midhun's example was a conceptual one, illustrating the difference between a class and instance method. But, while you want to call the instance method, you want to call this for your *existing* instance of your view controller, definitely not instantiating a new view controller.

   So, you may ask, how do you get a reference to the existing instance of your view controller? What you'll want to do is to (a) create a property in your app delegate to hold the reference to the view controller with the `saveData` method; (b) have that view controller set that property of the app delegate. So, first, create a property in your app delegate's .h file to reference the view controller:

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
   ```

   Obviously, don't forget the `#import "ViewController.h"` line early in the .h file.

   Second, have the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller update the app delegate's `viewController` property:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
       delegate.viewController = self;
   }
   ```

   Again, don't forget to `#import "AppDelegate.h"` at the top of your `ViewController.m` file.

   Having done that, then app delegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground` can now reference this property that you set in `viewDidLoad`

   ```
   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
   {
       [self.viewController saveData];
   }
   ```

   Frankly, if you did this technique, I might suggest further refinements, notably employing a delegate-protocol pattern, but I'm going to defer that conversation until after you have mastered the above technique.
2. Even easier than the above is to eliminate this app delegate `applicationDidEnterBackground` code altogether, and just have your view controller, itself, respond to the system notification that is associated with the app entering background. And, needless to say, you put this code right in the view controller itself.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveData) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
   }

   - (void)dealloc
   {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
   }

   - (void)saveData
   {
       // save your data here
   }
   ```

   As you can see, I register to observe `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` in `viewDidLoad`, but also make sure to remove my observer in `dealloc`. I also made sure that my `@selector` method name exactly matched my method name (e.g., in my example, no parameters, and hence no colon).

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed suggestions. I tried #1, since I came closer to understanding it. The app compiled and ran, but a new problem cropped up that prevents me from seeing your code work: the "mainActivityArray" which is supposed to get written to the plist always returns nil. I have no idea why--it worked fine until I incorporated your code, but I can't see how your code could have affected it:

Comment: - (IBAction)buttonHit:(id)sender
{
    DataClass *dataObject = [[DataClass alloc] init];
    UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    dataObject.timeTapped = NSDate.date;
    dataObject.buttonTapped = resultButton.currentTitle;
    NSDictionary *tapDictionary = @{ @"Time Tapped": dataObject.timeTapped,
                                     @"Activity Tapped": dataObject.buttonTapped};
    
    [self.mainActivityArray addObject:tapDictionary];
}

Comment: @TimJones Have you examined `mainActivityArray` and confirmed that it's not `nil`? I.e., have you actually instantiated a `NSMutableArray` before trying to add objects to it?

Comment: OK, a status report. This conversation is very helpful, but has also challenged many of the assumptions I had about my understanding of instantiation, delegation, and more. As a result, I'm going to go into the app (it's small and simple) and pull most of it out by the roots, down to the storyboard, and that too if necessary. Many thanks for your patience and wisdom, and I'll report back here when I get the thing rebuilt incorporating the suggestions here.